# How to exit Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I have. I am reading from one sheet and searching for that term on another sheet. If the search finds the match, it will copy that whole row and paste it onto the first sheet. The search, copy, and paste work. I do not recieve an error but it is as if the macro does not stop because Excel won't let me click out of the original cell the macro read. Am I missing a line of code that should end the macro? Ideally, it should just end the macro after the paste.

I went off the code from another thread:
[How to Paste copied Row from one Sheet to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409611/how-to-paste-copied-row-from-one-sheet-to-another)

```
Sub Ref()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

If Range("A11") = "SELECT" Then
    Else
    Set rng1 = Worksheets("MAIN").Range("A11")
    For Each rng2 In Worksheets("REF").Range("A11:A2000")

        If rng1 = rng2(1).Value Then
            rng2.EntireRow.Copy
            rng1.EntireRow.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next rng2
End If
End Sub
```

This is where I call the macro

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Selection_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Ref
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you running your procedure? On a button click or an event?

Comment: I have question to help my ignorance.  Can there be more than one `rng2` in `Worksheets("REF").Range("A11:A2000")`?  Wouldn't there be only one?

Comment: Andy- The Main calls the Macro on a SelectionChange

Comment: Smandoli-The For Each for rng2 will search the long column of names, so it will just find the first one that matches, does that clarify?

Comment: SelectionChange is a pretty "twitchy" event, so I'm wondering if you can invoke it in a more controlled way, and if that helps.  Like from the Immediate window.  For testing.

Comment: I am new to vba so I don't really know what that means. I bascially just need to Macro to run when user selects from the dropdown menu in cell A11.

Comment: You may benefit from this article:  http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: It would be helpful to also include the relevant `selection_change` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the paste from re-triggering the change event:

```
...
Application.EnableEvents=False
rng1.EntireRow.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas)
Application.EnableEvents=True
...
```

**EDIT:** You should probably be using the `worksheet_change` event, not `selection_change`. You can handle the event enabling there instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If not application.intersect(me.range("A11"),Target) is nothing then
       Application.EnableEvents=False
       Call Ref
       Application.EnableEvents=True
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: If I switch the True and False, the copy and paste works and I can click on a different cell, but it won't copy and paste if I change what is in the cell a second time. Cell A11 is a dropdown list in case I didn't mention that. Any idea why it won't paste new data with another new selection? I thought the macro would run anytime that cell changes.

Comment: If you switch the true and false, then you exit the sub with events still disabled, and it's not going to fire any change events the next time you select a value.  That setting is persistent - it doesn't set back to true unless you set it back.